# typescript angular array looping, but doesn't loop explanation

Tags: angular, typescript

```
LoadDetail(kodeGolGaji){
    this.loading = true;
    this.golonganGajiService.detailGolonganGaji(kodeGolGaji).subscribe(
      r => {
        this.loading = false;
        if (r.length) {
          this.data = r;
          console.log(r);
        } else {
          console.log("no data");
        }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

In subcribe function, r variable is an array. 
what does that grammatical mean?

I was not expexting a looping. What does array => {code} what is the name of this grammatical? is it only in type script or is it es 6?

Comment: The code snipped you have provided does not use any loop functions. Use `r.forEach()` if you need to loop over `r` inside the subscribe's `{}` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach.

Comment: What's your question? What are you expecting to do the loop? Subscribe will return whatever value is returned from your service - in your case an array. You have to process that value yourself.

Comment: BTW, if you know is a array, "type" the response as `.subscribe((r:any[])={...})`

Comment: I was not expexting a looping.
What does array => {code}
what is the name of this grammatical? is it only in type script or is it es 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to loop over `r` inside `subscribe()` block use:

```
r => {
    this.loading = false;
    if (r.length) {
        r.forEach((item) => {
            // your loop
        });
        this.data = r;
        console.log(r);
    } else {
        console.log("no data");
    }
}
```

> what does that grammatical mean?

`if (r.length) {`

*If array has items*. [JavaScript array length explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length).

`this.data = r;`

*Assign the value of array to `this.data`.*